# JavaScript - Run callback after all fetch requests to finish in multiple for loops - errored or not

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I'm writing a little proof of concept thing, which downloads all my HTML assets via `fetch()`. Currently, I query all the tags with a compatible asset and run it through a for loop for each asset type. What I need to do is run a callback function after all the requests in the loops have finished. I tried await but it downloads each asset one by one. How can I do this?

```js
const scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
const links = document.querySelectorAll("link");
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
for (const script of scripts) {
    (async (s) => {
        const doIgnore = s.getAttribute("data-ignoreload");
        if (doIgnore) return;
        const src = s.getAttribute("data-src");
        if (!src) {
            console.error("Script does not have a data-src prop.");
            return;
        }
        fetch(src)
            .then(x => x.text())
            .then(r => {
                const newScript = document.createElement("script");
                newScript.innerHTML = r;
                document.body.appendChild(newScript);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(`Error loading script with src ${src}: ${err}`);
            });
    })(script);
}
for (const link of links) {
    (async (l) => {
        const doIgnore = l.getAttribute("data-ignoreload");
        if (doIgnore) return;
        const rel = l.getAttribute("rel");
        if (!(rel == "stylesheet")) {
            return;
        }
        const href = l.getAttribute("data-href");
        if (!href) {
            console.error("Stylesheet does not have a data-href prop.");
            return;
        }
        fetch(href)
            .then(x => x.text())
            .then(r => {
                const newStyle = document.createElement("style");
                newStyle.innerHTML = r;
                document.head.append(newStyle);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(`Error loading stylesheet with href ${href}: ${err}`);
            });
    })(link);
}
for (const image of images) {
    (async (i) => {
        const doIgnore = i.getAttribute("data-ignoreload");
        if (doIgnore) return;
        const src = i.getAttribute("data-src");
        if (!src) {
            console.error("Image does not have a data-src prop.");
            return;
        }
        fetch(src)
            .then(x => x.blob())
            .then(r => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(r);
                i.setAttribute("src", url);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(`Error loading image ${src}: ${err}`);
            });
    })(image);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push all of your promises into an array, and then use `Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {})`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled

Example:

```js
const promises = images.map(async (image) => {
    // do some async work
    return fetch(whatever); // don't .catch this

})

Promise.allSettled(promises).then((results) => {
  // results is a result of errors or successes
})
```